# How to exclude "node_modules"

Tags: webpack, mocha.js, mocha-webpack

How can I exclude `node_modules` from the run?

[image: mocha-webpack]

I thought that `webpack-node-externals` were meant for this task. This is my `webpack.test-config.js`:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const config = {};

// in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
config.target = 'node';

// in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
config.externals = [nodeExternals()];

config.output = {
    // sourcemap support for IntelliJ/Webstorm
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]',
    devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]?[hash]'
};

// 'cheap-module-source-map' faster than 'source-map'
config.devtool = "source-map";


module.exports = config;
```

I run the tests from `package.json`:

`"test": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config webpack.config-test.js  \"**/test/*.test.js\"",`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code and see comments for details.
See this link for detail:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
...
module.exports = {
...
target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs,     etc. 
externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in   node_modules folder 
...
};
```

Comment: Man, that's the very same I already have. Only I have assigned the object to a variable `config`. ;)